# Can't set larger resolution than Full HD on a QHD monitor

Tags: linux, laptop, fedora, hdmi, resolution

Hi I have a Dell Vostro 3400 notebook with an Intel Core i5-1135G7 CPU and Intel Iris Xe integrated graphics. Everything tells me that I should be able to set QHD resolution when plugging in my monitor (Philips 245E). The Intel site says that it should support much higher resolutions, I'm using an HDMI cable, I checked with different cables.
I'm using Fedora Workstation. This is the xrandr output for my HDMI connected screen:

```
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1280x1440     59.91
   1680x1050     59.88
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      59.90
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   832x624       74.55
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
```

I know that this monitor supports QHD well, because it worked with a different notebook. I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Your CPU (and its internal GPU) is very new. Are you sure Fedora knows how to handle it properly? It could be that Fedora falls back on a generic Intel GPU driver that won't go higher than Full-HD.

Comment: @Tonny Sorry, I forgot to mention an important thing – this laptop also has Windows installed and there is no qhd option on it either.
Is there a way to check if Fedora is unable to handle it or is falling back on generic Intel driver?

Comment: Your laptop supports HDMI 1.4. There is the question of the quality of the HDMI cable. Note that according to [Wikipedia HDMI 1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4) using 4K video is done at 24 Hz.

Comment: @harrymc I checked with different HDMI cables, and nothing worked. I didn't say anything about 4k. There shouldn't be a problem with HDMI 1.4 and QHD (1440p).

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue when upgrading work laptop from an old Dell with intel hd graphics 620 to a newer Dell with Intel Xe Graphics.
I resolved the issue using a UCB-C dock-station and a displayport cable instead of a direct HDMI cable (which worked completely fine with the old laptop). I will try shortly with a UCB-C to DisplayPort cable as well

Answer (score 0):

My laboratory just acquire a Dell Vostro 15 3510 laptop for a project. I was having this problem in Windows, so I searched for specifications and they say that this model just accept FullHD. So, I updated the Windows version from 10 to 11 and few days after I saw that there was a 4k option in the display setting menu. It works normally 4k in Windows.

After that, I installed Ubuntu 20.04, but the maximum resolution is FullHD.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144411)